# Will old flats always have a crack and holes problem?

Tags: building

I'm currently filling a lot of cracks and holes in my very old flat.  Once I'm done I'm hoping I won't have to be doing any more filling.

As I have a lot of sensitivities I've been advised to move to a new build flat which tend to have less problems.  Someone advised me that I'm going to continue to have problems whilst I stay in older buildings.  However once Im done filling and sealing I dont expect there will be any more issues.

Is there anything about an old flat that predisposes it to develop more cracks and holes such that after I finish my work, more issues will arise?

Thanks.

Comment: Are holes in the roof or walls? What is it constructed out of..? (List in order from outside to inside.)

Comment: Any build without a vapor barrier will have a problem and even some that do have a vapor barrier will have problems. You can have a blower test done to evaluate how much any property leaks.

Answer (score 2):

If your foundations, roof and exterior walls are sound then you should not see any new cracks forming.

If they are not your house will continue to fall down in slow motion and cracks will continue to form.

Answer (score 1):

If your sensitivities are from air infiltrating through openings are not common to a properly maintained home, such as a number of your posts suggests. Once you are done, that should be it, since it appears you are working on other peoples shoddy work, finishing what they should have.

If you sensitivities are from interior contaminates and they are not bothering you now, then you will be ok, since nothing would appear with out something introducing them, such as leaks in the plumbing system or in a roof, for mildew for example. With the homes I see built today, new homes are not immune to having these issues too.

Comment: +1 for "new homes can have these problems too". Many new buildings are _very_ well built. Many other new buildings are thrown up as quickly as humanly possible with a minimum of care and concern. They meet the bare minimum of code standards so the inspector will pass them, and that's it. These buildings will have _at least_ as many issues as the one you're currently in.